# How do you make one nested cell of a flexbox overflow: scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I have looked at every similar question on Stack Overflow but none of them address [this specific scenario](https://codepen.io/t3db0t/pen/PoyGzKb).

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">Top area</div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="filters">Filters</div>
      <div class="scrollContainer">
        <ul class="item">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>5</li>
          <li>6</li>
          <li>7</li>
          <li>8</li>
          <li>9</li>
          <li>0</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">Main area</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top {
  height: 150px;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  background-color: #594255;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scrollContainer {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.item {
  margin: 1px;
  
  background-color: #fff;
  
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #594255;
   
  flex: 1;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

I want the white div to scroll when it overflows, and everything else stay fixed. What is the simplest way to achieve this without using fixed (pixel) heights?

Comment: What is "everything else" that should stay fixed? You are not restricting the white DIV (or some of its ancestors) to any height. Moreover, the DIV may overflow its ancestor `.left`, but that overflow is hidden. Consider using [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) in some places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you only need to set the height for the wrapper (currently this `html`), this will be enough. And then `flexbox` will do everything:

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body {
  flex: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 1px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.container {
  flex: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 1px;
  background-color: #594255;
}

.top {
  height: 150px;
  flex: none;
}

.bottom {
  flex: auto;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.filters {
  flex: none;
}

.scrollContainer {
  flex: auto;
  min-height: 1px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.item {
  margin: 1px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #594255;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">Top area</div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="filters">Filters</div>
      <div class="scrollContainer">
        <ul class="item">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>5</li>
          <li>6</li>
          <li>7</li>
          <li>8</li>
          <li>9</li>
          <li>0</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">Main area</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some fixed height somewhere along the line to trigger the overflow. That, along with flex properties, should do the trick in this case for taller screens. You'll still need to decide what height you want for shorter screens. Here's an example:

```css
body {
  /* height: 100%; */ /* percentage height won't work here without defined height on parent (html) element */
  height: 100vh; /* new; simple solution */
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  height: 100%; /* works because height defined on parent (body) element */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #594255;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* new; disable shrink */
  height: 150px;
}

.bottom {
  height: calc(100vh - 150px); /* new */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  height: 100%; /* new */
  display: flex; /* new */
  flex-direction: column; /* new */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scrollContainer {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.item {
  margin: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #594255;
   
  flex: 1;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">Top area</div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="filters">Filters</div>
      <div class="scrollContainer">
        <ul class="item">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>5</li>
          <li>6</li>
          <li>7</li>
          <li>8</li>
          <li>9</li>
          <li>0</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">Main area</div>
  </div>
</div>
```